# How to import turf modules properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, turfjs

This should be straigh forward.

`yarn add turf`

and then - according to [documentation](https://turfjs.org/getting-started):

```
// Import your module of interest
var collect = require('@turf/collect');
// or in ES6
import collect from '@turf/collect';
```

But, when I try any of these, it does not work. I get

> Unable to resolve module `@turf/collect`.

When I check the `node_modules` folder, I see that `turf` installed properly (at least there are folders and there is something in them).

[image: node modules folder]

I tried this in a `react-native` project:

1. `watchman watch-del-all`
2. Delete `node_modules` and freshly `yarn install`
3. Reset Metro's cache with `yarn start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace changed.
Turf must be installed with `@turf/turf`, i.e. `yarn add @turf/turf`

Answer (score 1):

I was led to this question for a related problem.

To import a specfic module with a name that is more than one word it becomes camel case like so:

```
import nearestPointOnLine from '@turf/nearest-point-on-line';
import booleanPointInPolygon from '@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon';
```